# What is the differences between & and && in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I understand that && short-circuits the evaluation so it doesn’t have to evaluate the RHS if it doesn’t have to but what about EF? Is there any differences between & and && (same for | and ||)? performance-wise!

Comment: If you need it for ef (Core or not), and you want conditions I‘d suggest to always use && or ||. Because bitwise operators are out of your experience at the moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> but what about EF? Is there any differences between & and && (same for | and ||)? performance-wise!

Yes, there is.

First, sometimes EF Core uses [client evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval), so it can't be short-circuited.

Second, even when using server evaluation, EF Core translates them differently. For instance, here is the translation for SqlServer:

```
LINQ             SQL
==============   ============ 
expr1 && expr2   expr1 AND expr2
expr1 & expr2    (expr1 & expr2) = 1
```

Whether this affects the performance depends of the database query optimizer, but the first looks generally better. And some database providers which has no native support for `bool` type might generate quite inefficient translation or even fail to translate the `&` / `|` predicates.

Shortly, preferably always use logical `&&` and `||` operators in LINQ queries.

Comment: Great! But did not understand this line `so it can't be short-circuited.`

Comment: @TanvirArjel I meant, when executed client side, it uses the same evaluation rules as the corresponding C# code. e.g. `&&` and `||` will short-circuit, `&` and `|` will not.

Comment: I have understood this ! but in case of sql server `expr1 AND expr2` does not behave the same way as C# `expr1 && expr2`? or anything else.

Comment: @TanvirArjel  The *short-circuit* part makes the difference for *client evaluation*. For *server evaluation*  the difference is in the SQL translation, which most likely will affect the performance due to non natural `WHERE` conditions.

Comment: My question is : in case of `expr1 AND  expr2` in SQL server , if the first operand is false, will the second operand be evaluated or not?

Comment: @TanvirArjel How the query is evaluated depends on database query optimizers and the query execution plans they create. They are allowed to do many things - reordering the conditions (in order to use index) etc, so in general you question cannot be answered.

Comment: I am one step away of up-voting your answer :) Another question: in case of `(expr1 & expr2) = 1` in SQL server, What impact it will create in the query, I am not sure about this?

Comment: @TanvirArjel Again, how the SQL translation affects the query plan is unknown. SqlServer might be smart and treat it similar to `AND`, or might be not. And Oracle for instance would definitely have issues with both translation and execution. The point is, `AND` and `OR` are the **natural** ways of representing binary logical conditions inside SQL predicates. The idea of SQL is to describe the desired result, not *how* to do that. Which is different from LINQ to Objects where the execution depends on how you compose the query.

Comment: Okay! Thanks you so much I shall experiment these in SQL server level.

Answer (score 2):

According to Microsoft Documentation:

1.The [& Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/and-operator) is supported in two forms: **a unary address-of operator** or  **a binary logical operator.**

**Unary address-of operator:**

The unary `&` operator returns the address of its operand. For more information, see [How to: obtain the address of a variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/how-to-obtain-the-address-of-a-variable) . The address-of operator `&` requires unsafe context.

**Integer logical bitwise AND operator:**

For integer types, the `&` operator computes the logical bitwise `AND` of its operands:

```
uint a = 0b_1111_1000;
uint b = 0b_1001_1111;
uint c = a & b;
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(c, toBase: 2));
// Output:
// 10011000
```

2.The [&& Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-and-operator) is the conditional logical AND operator, also known as the "short-circuiting" logical AND operator, computes the logical AND of its bool operands. The result of `x && y` is true if both `x` and `y` evaluate to `true`. Otherwise, the result is `false`. If the first operand evaluates to `false`, the second operand is not evaluated and the result of operation is `false`.The following example demonstrates that behavior:

```
bool SecondOperand()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Second operand is evaluated.");
    return true;
}

bool a = false && SecondOperand(); // <-- second operand is not evaluated here
Console.WriteLine(a);
// Output:
// False

bool b = true && SecondOperand(); // <-- second operand is evaluated here
Console.WriteLine(b);
// Output:
// Second operand is evaluated.
// True
```

**Now in case of EF/EF Core behavior @Ivan Stoev explained it greatly:** [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54782136/5928070)

Comment: Thanks @TanvirArjel the question is about EF behavior

Answer (score 2):

I decided to do an experiment:

```
var t1 = _db.Customers
.Where(x => x.FirstName == "james" | x.FirstName == "thomas")
.Select(x=>x.CustomerId).ToList();
```

vs.

```
var t2 = _db.Customers
.Where(x => x.FirstName == "james" || x.FirstName == "thomas")
.Select(x => x.CustomerId).ToList();
```

t1 was executed as:

```
SELECT [x].[CustomerId]
FROM [Customers] AS [x]
WHERE (CASE
    WHEN [x].[FirstName] = N'james'
    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
END | CASE
    WHEN [x].[FirstName] = N'thomas'
    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
END) = 1
```

and t2 as :

```
SELECT [x].[CustomerId]
FROM [Customers] AS [x]
WHERE [x].[FirstName] IN (N'james', N'thomas')
```

Both returns same result. I compared their execution plan, to execute t1 I had "Index Scan" while to execute t2 I had "Index Seek". As Justin mentioned ([SQL Server Plans : difference between Index Scan / Index Seek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136524/sql-server-plans-difference-between-index-scan-index-seek)) "Seeks are always better to have than scans as they are more efficient in the way it looks data up".

So, using | or & not only it may leads to client side evaluation but it will affect the generated sql as well.

Thanks everyone!